# Spring batch xmlns xsd schema error

Tags: xml, spring, xsd, config, spring-batch

I am developing an application using Spring Batch in eclipse

Error I while starting the server is

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'notificationController' defined in ServletContext       
 resource [/WEB-INF/springbatch-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 
 'com.confluence14.utility.Notifier#72372ef8' of type 
 [com.confluence14.utility.Notifier] while setting constructor argument; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
 Error creating bean with name 'com.confluence14.utility.Notifier#72372ef8' defined in 
 ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springbatch-config.xml]: 
 Cannot resolve reference to 
 bean 'dispatchMailsJob' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
 'dispatchMailsJob': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type 
 [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean] while setting 
 bean property 'flow'; ......and so on.......
```

My xml file used to config spring batch is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        ">

    <batch:job id="dispatchMailsJob" restartable="false" job-repository="jobRepository">
        <batch:step id="dispatchMailsStep">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="mailIdReader" writer="mailWriter" commit-interval="10" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="mailIdReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="sql" value="select #{jobParameters['tablename']}.user_id, login_credential.email
                                        from #{jobParameters['tablename']} 
                                        inner join login_credential 
                                        on #{jobParameters['tablename']}.user_id = login_credential.user_id 
                                        where #{jobParameters['tablename']}.#{jobParameters['attribute.name']} = '#{jobParameters['attribute.value']}' 
                                        and #{jobParameters['tablename']}.mapping_type >= '#{jobParameters['mappingType']'};
                                        " />
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.confluence14.utility.batch.MailIdRowMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailWriter" class="com.confluence14.utility.batch.MailWriter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mailer" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="#{jobParameters['mail.text']}" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="#{jobParameters['mail.subject']}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailer" class="com.confluence14.utility.Mailer">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="mailSender" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
        <property name="port" value="25"/>
        <property name="username" value="marg.ipicas@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="todayisTGMC"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="notificationController" class="com.confluence14.controller.NotificationController" >
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <bean class="com.confluence14.utility.Notifier" >
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jobLauncher" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" ref="dispatchMailsJob" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Now the problem lies in xmlns part at the top of this config file.

In this config file the last bean I declared `notificationController` tries to refer the bean named `dispatchMailsJob` which is the first bean declared above but is unable to recognize it.

I am struck on for days. 
This is my second project in spring batch and I remember that the same issue consumed days in my first project also. (I now don't have access to the code of my first project)

Kindly help me out with what exactly should I write in the xmlns schema part

The spring related libraries I am using are

```
spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-retry-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need `scope="step"` for beans using late-binding (`#{jobParameters[...]}` for example); spring can't create job bean because it can't resolve batch-related spEL expressions